# How to use await function in coroutine from non-suspended function in Kotlin Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I want to wait for result, but the problem is I want to do this operation in background thread. I researched about this and got to know about async(), but to use async, my actual function should be also suspend, that is not possible, because that actual function is calling from overridden library so I can't make it suspendable!

Code:

```
 override fun authenticate(route: Route?, response: Response): Request? {
    return when (tokenProvider.isUserLoggedIn() && countOfResponse(response) <= AppConstants.INetworkValues.RETRY_API_LIMIT) {
        true -> {
            authenticateByRefreshToken(response).also {
            LogUtils.d("API Request: $it")}}
        else -> return null
    }
}
```

---

```
    @Synchronized
    private fun authenticateByRefreshToken(response: Response): Request? {
        .....

        //TODO: Here I want to remove runblocking and want to use async
        val newRefreshTokenResponse: Resource<RefreshTokenResponse?> = runBlocking { refreshTokenImpl.refreshToken() }
        
.....
    }
```

Please help.

Comment: you want to call this function authenticateByRefreshToken()

Comment: @Vikas yes, this [refreshTokenImpl.refreshToken()] I want to call from authenticateByRefreshToken

Comment: For the case of `Authenticator` the only possible solution is to use `runBlocking`, and it's the same as using async await because in this case there is no UI that will blocked, so using `runBlocking` in this case is not that bad and it is the same as using async await

Comment: @MohamedRejeb The login scrren will be blocked right, because from there I'm making a call through Retrofit

Comment: @ShyneilSingh make the call from a background thread and add progress bar to the login screen when you are waiting for the response, you will notice that the UI is not blocked, also in all cases `authenticate` will not return only is there is a response, so even with async await the function will keep waiting for the result, it's the same thing in this case and also using `runBlocking` is the best option here, try adding progress bar in the ui and you will notice that it's not blocked

Comment: @MohamedRejeb So if you're saying that if I started any api call using retrofit and in that if I do anything which is doing on main thread, still it work as a background thread only?

Comment: @ShyneilSingh of course the the api call should be on a background thread, I'm talking only about the case of the `Authenticator` because I was asking the same question as you, I thought that using runBlocking in the Authenticator is not a good idea until I figured out that it is the best possible solution, and it's not going to block nothing

Comment: let me explain, when we make an api request it's going to block the code after it right, ok now if we move that api request in a background thread so the code after it will not be blocked, but in this function there is no other code except the runBlocking and the function must wait for the response to end, so in all cases the code after this function can't be executed without the response

Comment: @MohamedRejeb Yes, that is fine that it is waiting to finish task, but if user is doing something on UI, thet should not be blacked

Comment: Is this library that you have to override functions in a public library that you can share the name of? And if so, which class are you subclassing here?That would help us to suggest solutions.

Comment: It's okhttp library, which we use along with retrofit to mail API call and I use Authenticator class by OkHttp for tokenization.

Answer (score 1):

A function with this signature:

```
override fun authenticate(route: Route?, response: Response): Request? {
```

requires a *synchronous* result. That means a coroutine will not help you at this task at all. Coroutines are launched *asynchronously* (but the code inside the coroutine is synchronous). Asynchronous means it will not return a result directly. A launched coroutine returns a Job or Deferred, which you can wait for *only inside other coroutines*.

You could wrap your coroutine code in `runBlocking` instead of using `launch`, but then of course it will block the thread it is called from, so you have not accomplished anything by using a coroutine. `runBlocking` only makes sense if you have suspend functions that you need to call synchronously without a coroutine, or that you need to run in parallel while still blocking the calling thread.

I don't use Retrofit/OkHttp much, so I'm not exactly sure about this, but from briefly looking at the [documentation](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-authenticator/), this appears to be an interface that you hand over to OkHttp to use. In that case, there is no reason whatsoever for you to attempt to convert it into asynchronous code. OkHttp is the one calling the function, not your own code, so you cannot control what thread it will be called from. That will be up to OkHttp, and presumably, it will sensibly run the code in an appropriate thread (maybe its asynchronous behavior can be configured elsewhere in your OkHttp setup).

Answer (score 0):

Then you can call this function under the scope of Coroutine like

```
CoroutineScope(Dispactchers.IO).launch{
authenticateByRefreshToken()
// now you can use suspend keyword with further functions
}
```

Comment: Can you write the full code? Also can you make sure that whatever the logic I've written inside authenticate() overridden function that will wait for all this background task?

Comment: look I can't write complete code because I don't have the same code you have. so you must try with your code its hardly take 5 - 10 imntes

Comment: OK I'll but can you make sure about authenticate() overridden function that will wait for all this background task? –

Comment: its the core functionality of coroutine to suspend and resume process or wait until work is not done

Comment: Thanks Vikas, let me test and if it works then I'll accept the answer.

Comment: This is not working as CoroutineScope is returning Job but I want Request

Comment: use async and call .await on it